# Relative Import Confusion in Python

Tags: python, import, importerror

I am having some trouble figuring out how to do relative imports in Python.  I am currently working on my first major project so I want to do it right using unit tests.  However, I am having trouble with my file structure and relative imports.

Here is my current structure:

```
App/
  __init__.py
  src/
    __init__.py
    person.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    person_tests.py
```

What I want to do is be able to import person.py into person_tests.py for the unit tests.  I have attempted the following:

```
from . import person
from .. import person
from .App.src import person
from ..App.src import person
from ..src.person import *
from ..src import person
from .src import person
```

Every one of the above throws either a syntax error or

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Can someone please clarify this for me?

**Edit**: Python version is 2.7.
**Edit**: I would like to be able to use this with say unittest or nose.

Comment: I think absolute imports are the preferred way in most cases. [Some reading](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) (don't miss the section after that one about relative imports).

Comment: You can add a (possibly) empty "`__init__.py`" file in "`App`" directory to make it a package

Comment: Oops. I forgot to mention that I DO have an `__init__.py` file in the App directory.  Updating question.

Comment: What Python version? This has changed (radically) over time, so it's pretty hard to give an answer without knowing which version the question is for

Comment: Also, how are you running the code in `person_tests.py`? In particular, are you running code from outside of the package that does an `import App.tests.person_tests`, or are you just `cd`ing into the middle of the package and doing `python person_tests.py` or something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could append it to sys.path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../src")
import person
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: By appeding a directory to the Python path, you are telling that there is a new directory to search for files/modules

Comment: This will work, but it's a bad idea. You tend to end up with the same module imported twice under different names (which means two separate copies of each global, etc.). [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) explains why. If you must do this, append the top level of the package to the path, and absolute-import it.

Answer (score 7):

My guess (and I'll delete this if I'm wrong) is that you're trying to use `person_tests.py` as a top-level script, rather than as a module inside a package, by doing something like this:

```
$ cd App/tests
$ python person_tests.py
```

In that case, `person_tests` does not end up as `App.tests.person_tests`, but as just `__main__` (or, with minor variations, as the top-level `person_tests`, which has the same basic issues). So, `..` does not refer to `App`, and therefore there is no way to get to `person` as a relative import.

More generally, nothing on `PYTHONPATH`, including `.`, should ever be in the middle of any package directory, or things will get broken.

The right answer is to not do that. Do something like this:

```
$ python -m App.tests.person_tests
```

Or write a top-level (outside the package) script that imports the module, and run that top-level script.

Comment: So I guess you are recommending that I write my own pythonic unittest runner.

Comment: @DaBungalow: Not at all. Either use a standard unittest runner, or keep things simple and run your tests manually, but do so in a way that works instead of a way that doesn't work. I suppose a trivial wrapper script around the way that works could count as a custom unittest runner, but really, we're talking about a one-liner there…

Comment: OK. That just reminded me I left something very important out. I would like to be able to use unittest or nose.

Comment: @DaBungalow: OK, so go through the docs or tutorial for whichever one you want to use. Both of them make it easy to write multiple tests organized in subpackages and run them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Just as abarnert says, you can not excute the script as main for the relative import based on the current name of the script. Quoted from the doc:

> Note that both explicit and implicit relative imports are based on the
>   name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is
>   always "__main__", modules intended for use as the main module of a
>   Python application should always use absolute imports.

`.` represents the current package and `..` represents the parent package. So some of your  import statement is wrong.

```
from . import person # wrong for no person module in package tests
from .. import person # wrong for no person module in package app
from .App.src import person # wrong for no app package in package tests
from ..App.src import person # wrong for no app package in package app
from ..src.person import * # right
from ..src import person # right
from .src import person # wrong
```

You can refer [PEP328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for the standard of relative import.